# Dividing an ODE by a variable that is not the zero function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$y'=y^2, y(0)=1$

so when I transform $y'$ to $dy/dx$ and then divide by $y^2$ I say that $y$ doesn't equal to zero.

But what should I do with the possible solution of a function that is zero for all $x$ except for $x=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $y(x)$ is continuos and it is equal to $1$ in $x=0$ so there exists a neighborhood of $x=0$ such that the function $y$ is different from zero. In this neighborhood you can divide the equation with $\frac{1}{y^2}$ and you can compute the ODE. Then you must find the maximal definition domain of the solution $y$.

In your case you get $y(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ in some neighborhood of $x=0$ and it is clear that you can extended it only in $(-\infty, 1)$.

Comment: So you're saying that because I divided by a y that is continuous and has a neighbourhood of x where y doesn't equal to zero I simply should mention the maximal domain of the solution I found?

Comment: @Raz sure, because you can extend your local function to Its maximal domain (containing the Point x=0) and then you can verify your new function sarisfies that ODE